# jQuery - How to trigger an event after reload - ONLY ONCE

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, onchange, reload

So this is what I am trying to do - I want everytime the user selects a different option at the 'select', a different function would be activated. Each 'selected:option' has a different function.
It might be easier to understand with the following code:

```
$('.edd-variable-pricing-switcher').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == 1) {
            $('.chackout-licence-private').css('display', 'block');
        }
        else {
            $('.chackout-licence-private').css('display', 'none');
        }

    if(e.originalEvent) {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
}).change();
```

Now it works, when I choose the option with the value '1' in my select (select class=".edd-variable-pricing-switcher"), I have the div with the class ".chackout-licence-private" displayed block. 
My problem is - The page never stop to reloads itself. as I trigger the change event at the end, it causes an endless page reload, but without triggering the change event, after the page reloads the changes wouldn't exist anymore.

The solution I am trying to look for, is how can I trigger the change event after the page reloads only once, so the page won't keep reloading in sort of a loop.

Thanks

***EDIT***

I am adding some of the code..
1. This is the html I'm trying affect and display (normally it is display:none):

```
<div class="chackout-licence">
    <div class="chackout-licence-private">
        <h3>Private Licence</h3>
            <p>
            A single track licence for online entertainment video....
            </p>
  </div><!--chackout-licence-private-->
```

2. The select and the option code part is from a plugin, so I'm adding an image from the inspect element:
   [image]
3. explanation: I am trying to create a variable pricing for a product, so at the checkout the user would be able to decide with which licence he will buy the product. so he chooses an option from the select, and than each option displays a different description about each licence.

Comment: Hint: use cookies or HTML 5 storage to track previous activity

Comment: `$(function({ $('.edd-variable-pricing-switcher').trigger('change')}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I trigger the change event after the page reloads only once,
>   so the page won't keep reloading in sort of a loop

[EDIT] I think this one would work:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    /**
     * Hides (default) or shows an element.
     *
     * @param s    mixed A DOM selector. E.g. .my-class or #my-unique-id
     * @param show bool  If TRUE, shows the element. Otherwise, hides it.
     * @return object The target element.
     */
    function toggleDisplay( s, show ) {
        if ( show ) {
            return $( s ).show();
        } else {
            return $( s ).hide();
        }
    }

    /*
     * You may also instead target the SELECT's "name" value. I.e.
     * $( 'select[name="edd-variable-pricing-switcher[60]"]' )
     */
    $( 'select.edd-variable-pricing-switcher' ).each( function() {
        // Saves the default value. (on-page cache)
        $( this ).data( '_defaultValue', this.value );

        // When the value changes, reloads the page.
        $( this ).on( 'change', function() {
            var _defaultValue = $( this ).data( '_defaultValue' );

            // Invalid value.
            if ( ! this.value ) {
                // Hides .chackout-licence-private
                toggleDisplay( '.chackout-licence-private' );
            }
            // It's the default value. ("no" changes)
            else if ( this.value === _defaultValue ) {
                /*
                 * Shows .chackout-licence-private, if value is 1; otherwise,
                 * hides it.
                 */
                toggleDisplay( '.chackout-licence-private', '1' === this.value );
            }
            // It's a valid new value.
            else {
                // The TRUE below - are you 100% sure you want to force reload?
                window.location.reload( true );
            }
        } );

        /*
         * When the page loads (i.e. first load or after a reload), shows/hides
         * the appropriate DIV. In this case, we show .chackout-licence-private
         * if value is 1; otherwise, hides it.
         */
        toggleDisplay( '.chackout-licence-private', '1' === this.value );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It still doesn't work for me. the page reloads itself non stop.

Comment: Something is still wrong in here, can't figure this out. The page keep reloads itself..

Comment: Ok. I have edited the question. hope it will help. Now the what happens is that the page reloads itself no matter what the value is.

Comment: Thank you for the update. So, if for example, I chose "*The Bird | one - $10.00*", the page will reload and there is a PHP code/function that will apply the selection, without actually submitting the form? (I hope you understand my question..)

Comment: Also, in the JS code you provided, if user chose the option with the value of `1`, the *chackout-licence-private* `DIV` will be visible. Now what if the user chooses a different option? Is there a different `DIV` that will be made visible instead of the *chackout-licence-private*? Or will the `DIV`'s content change *after the page is reloaded*? I'm actually slightly confused as to why the page is reloaded just after the `DIV` is made visible.

Comment: Hey Sally. ok, so if you choose "The Bird | one - $10.00", there is a php code that will apply the selection by reloading the page.

Comment: If the user chose the option with the value of '1', the he 'chackout-licence-private ' DIV will be visible. If the user chose a different option, there will be a different div that will be visible. I saw the jsfiddle example, that is what I want eventually, but as I said before, after the user select one of the option, the js code works just fine, but the page will reload itself, and after the reload the js code won't be effective anymore. So I need to find a way for the new visible DIV to stay visible after the page reloads. Hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So when an option is selected, the page *needs* to and will be reloaded; and the *checkout-license-private* DIV will be visible *only* after the reload; is that true?

Comment: Hey @Sally, thanks a lot for your help! It works now:) I didn't need to force a reload, cause the reload call already existed, I needed the code to work even after the page reload. So I changed the else part in case of 'It's a valid new value.' , so instead of reloading I 'toggeledclass' other value and divs. Anyway everything works now. Thanks again I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome! =) And I'm sorry for the typo in my previous comment — I wrote *chAckout* as *chEckout*. xD

Comment: oh. Thank you for that:) I see I did a mess with that word

Answer (score 0):

Well you are tracking a change event, doing something in that function but right after you are triggering the change event again.

`$('.edd-variable-pricing-switcher').change(function() { ... }).change();` is your code. The last `.change()` triggers another change, hence repeating itself.

Simply remove the last `.change()` like so

`$('.edd-variable-pricing-switcher').change(function() {...});`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am triggering the change event again so after the page reloads the function will still be effective.  If I remove the last change, the page would reload only once, yes, but it won't save the function the change has made